# RegEx for decimal with N-digit precision

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to validate a `decimal` in the below range in my `MVC3` application.

> **0.000000001 to 100.000000000**

This is the `Regex` I tried but, it is not working:

> **(^100([.]0{1,9})?)$|(^\d{1,9}([.]\d{1,9})?)$**

```
  [RegularExpression(@"(^100([.]0{1,9})?)$|(^\d{1,9}([.]\d{1,9})?)$", 
   ErrorMessage ="Decimal value should be between 0.000000000 to 100.000000000")]
  [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = " % must be between {1} and {2}")]
  [Display(Name = "Percentage:")]
  public double? Percentage { get; set; }
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why not convert it to double? double.Parse(yourNumber)>.000000001

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: If you need absolute decimal precision you should be using a `decimal` instead of a `double`. There are some numbers that are representable in decimal but aren't accurately representable as a `double`.

Comment: What's the point of using the `RegularExpression` attribute on a property of type `double`?

Comment: Is it necessary to use regular expression for validation??? You can use range validator for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)\.\d{0,8}[1-9]$
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second alternative you allow 1 to 9 digits before the dot.

```
(^100([.]0{1,9})?)$|(^\d{1,9}([.]\d{1,9})?)$
                           ^
```

Change this to

```
^(100(\.0{1,9})?|\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,9})?)$
```

You can still "simplify" this, by moving the fraction out of the alternation

```
^(100|\d{1,2})(\.\d{1,9})?$
```

be aware that this expression does allow leading zeros like "00.1".

**See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33k97)**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick.

```
\d+\.\d{9}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be the required regex:

```
(\d|[1-9]\d)(\.\d{1,9})?|100(\.0{1,9})?
```

In your regex, `(^\d{1,9}([.]\d{1,9})?)$` matches one to nine digits **(may be nine 0s upto nine 9s)** followed by optional decimal part. This is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?:[1]\d)|(?:[1-9]))?\d\.\d{9}$
```

This will match your range.  Also, it will not match the odd scenario of a double zero preceding the decimal like such:  00.000000000.  So, 00.000000000 will not be a valid number.

If you want it with variable decimal places to the right of the 0, then you can use something like:

```
^(?:(?:[1]\d)|(?:[1-9]))?\d\.\d{1,9}$
```

edit:  sentence wording